# How to use awk to strip off characters last column of output?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have an output from a command that looks like this:

```
XYZ Server Version 15.2.8 (10095.48)
```

How can I use awk in order to print only 10095? (there might be 4 or 6 numbers instead of 5)

Also, if I have an output like:

```
XYZ Server Version: 12.2.4.8638
```

How can I print the output that follows the dot? It should look like this: 8638

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `-F` to define a "field separator":

> How can I use awk in order to print only 10095? (there might be 4 or 6 numbers instead of 5)

```
echo "XYZ Server Version 15.2.8 (10095.48)" | awk -F'(' '{print $2}' | awk -F')' '{print $1}' | awk -F'.' '{print $1}'
```

> How can I print the output that follows the dot? It should look like this: 8638

```
echo "XYZ Server Version: 12.2.4.8638" | awk -F'.' '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: this works very nicely. thank you

Comment: Using two `awk` are normally never need.

Comment: An additional operation was added just in case a line like `XYZ Server Version 15.2.8 (10095)` was found.

Answer (score -1):

This should do.

```
echo "XYZ Server Version 15.2.8 (10095.48)" | awk '{split($NF,a,"[(.]");print a[2]}'
10095
```

Split the last field `$NF` = `(10095.48)` by `(` and `.`, then print second part.

```
echo "XYZ Server Version: 12.2.4.8638" | awk -F. '{print $NF}'
8638
```

Comment: Would be nice to know why someone gives `-1`

Answer (score -1):

If `gawk` is an option, this seems to extract both formats:

```
match($0, /\(([0-9]+)\./, a) {print a[1];}
match($0, /Version: [0-9.]+\.([0-9]+)$/, a) {print a[1];}
```